# Command line arguments in Xcode throw error, but terminal works fine

Tags: c, xcode10

I've got a small program written in C for the purpose of copying one file into another, by passing two files as command line arguments.

If I try and set these in Xcode (version 10) under Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme, the program terminates because open(const char* pathname, int oflag, ...) returns -1, meaning it couldn't open the file.

However, if I repeat the same process and I compile and run the code through terminal, the program executes and copies the content of one file into the other.

The code that throws the error:

`if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
     //Result is -1, so it throws error
 }`

I've tried printing the arguments, to see if they are actually there with `printf("%s %s", argv[1], argv[2]);` and the output seems fine.

If I run the program through command line using

```
./test input.txt output.txt
```

everything works fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xcode, but here's a quick idea: Do you need to change or set the working directory in XCode?

Comment: @MOehm You were correct, I resolved the issue by fiddling with the working directory settings. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Well, it was more of a gut feeling than an educated answer. I'm glad the issue is resolved, though.